# How to match this pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this pattern amongst a large garble of HTML:

```
<td>SIP/159@PBX</td>
```

I want to match this, getting:

```
159
```

as the result. This pattern will always be the same, with the only difference being the number between the "/" and the "@".

I have no idea how to do this in JS Regex. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions explains how regular expressions work in JS. There is nothing JS specific you have consider for this expression.

Comment: Is the "SIP" and "@PBX" consistent? What can we expect to change here?

Comment: Yes I have, and I often do simple regex patterns, i'm just terrible at fancier matching and am trying to learn more as I go.

Comment: @James, yes, as stated above: "This pattern will always be the same,"

Comment: Then please post your attempts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you can use is like this:

```
/SIP\/(\d+)@PBX/
```

This finds:

```
text SIP
followed by a / (which is escaped so it isn't interpreted as the end of the regex)
followed by one or more digits (captured in a group delineated with parens)
followed by the text @PBX
```

And, then you pull out the first matched group if there's a match.

And, if you have nothing else to go on other than it's in a `<td>` in your page, then you can use this generic code that looks at all `<td>` elements in the page.  Ideally, you would use the structure of the page to more clearly target the appropriate `<td>` cells.

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var regex = /SIP\/(\d+)@PBX/;
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    var matches = tds[i].innerHTML.match(regex);
    if (matches) {
        var number = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
        // process the number here
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vDwfs/

---

If the HTML is not in your page, but in a string, then you can just use the same regex to search for it in the HTML string.  You could bracket it with `<td>` and `</td>` if that seems wise based on your context.

```
var matches, number;
var regex = /SIP\/(\d+)@PBX/g;
while (matches = regex.exec(htmlString)) {
    number = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
    // process the number here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze the string with the following regular expression:

```
var result = "<td>SIP/159@PBX</td>".match("\<td\>SIP\/([0-9]+)\@PBX\<\/td\>");
```

Then, the numbers you want will be stored in `result[1]`:

```
alert(result[1]);
```

The trick is to surround the part of the string that you want to isolate in parentheses. Then, the result of the match function is an array in which the first element is the whole string matched by the regular expression, then a new element for each group enclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the string stored in a variable named `html`

`html.match(/SIP\/([0-9]*)\@PBX/g)`

Answer (score 0):

try this: `"SIP/159@PBX".match(/[^\/]+\/([^@]+)@[\s\S]*/)[1]`